# "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" error when compiling Irrlicht project on MacOS

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, codeblocks, irrlicht

I have compiled and installed Irrlicht 1.8 on MacOSX 10.8. Then I created CodeBlocks project that uses Irrlicht. Now when I'm trying to compile it I get following error:

```
    "_objc_msgSend_stret", referenced from:
      irr::CIrrDeviceMacOSX::setResize(int, int)in libIrrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceMacOSX.o)
      irr::CIrrDeviceMacOSX::createWindow()      in libIrrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceMacOSX.o)
      irr::CIrrDeviceMacOSX::CIrrDeviceMacOSX(irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters const&)in libIrrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceMacOSX.o)
      irr::CIrrDeviceMacOSX::CIrrDeviceMacOSX(irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters const&)in libIrrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceMacOSX.o)
      -[AppDelegate windowDidResize:] in libIrrlicht.a(AppDelegate.o)
      -[AppDelegate windowWillResize:toSize:] in libIrrlicht.a(AppDelegate.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm guessing the problem is in the way I compiled Irrlicht. This is how I did it:

1. Used [this tutorial](http://dbrgames.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/compiling-irrlicht-1-7-2-with-mac-os-10-7-and-xcode-4-1/) to compile Irrlicht.
   When compiling I got 4 warning about using deprecated functions, but I decided that it can't cause my problem.
2. And [this](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/wiki/?n=Main.InstallingIrrlicht#BuildMacOSX) to install.

Can anyone please help me with that?
Thanks.

upd: I found out that this error only occurs when I attempt to call any Irrlicht function. With library just statically linked to project it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had had these type of errors with *Irrlicht* about two years ago on Mac OS X (10.6) but I really don't remember how I've fixed the problem.
I remember that it was related to the linker (as you) so I had to specify the libIrrlicht.a file in the **Xcode**'s *target* section and put a

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libIrrlicht.a")
```

in the code just after the includes (I think that I've placed the *.a* file in the project directory for a test).

---

P.S.: Have you specified to *Code::Blocks* where to look for the library ?
I remember that in **Xcode** (3.2.x) there was also different paths sections :)

P.P.S.: Are you sure that you have compiled Irrlicht correctly ? Maybe you have compiled it for i386 and not for x86_64 :P